# Measuring switching time of 5LN01SP (NMOS)

Tags: transistors, mosfet, inverter, nmos, fet

I am working on switching time test circuit for 5LN01SP [specification](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/4/2/3/5ln01sp.PDF).

[image]

This is my circuit:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Input test signal is (as per [specification](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/4/2/3/5ln01sp.PDF)) a pulse of 1kHz frequency:

PW = 10us
D.C. == 1%

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We can see the t_ON time of the input signal pulse is about 60ns.
Specification says t_ON of the transistor would be about 60ns (18 + 42).
To measure this (by measurement of time vs drain current) I take measure of voltage across one of two 47 Ohm resistors (see scope probe with yellow and red wires) and I get:

[image]
[image]
[image]

We can see that t_ON measured is more than 3 us (~3.5 us).
I would appreciate any help understanding reasons for such huge difference (3.5 us vs 60 ns).
Also not sure about that long observed t_OFF time (~200 us). It's surely because of capacitance, but again huge difference from spec's 295 ns.

### [EDIT 1]

I tried shorten gnd and tip connection of the probe with following setup, though inductance and capacitance loaded into testing circuit by scope did not change.

[image]

### [EDIT 2]

I changed where the gnd tip of the probe is connecting to by connecting it to GND of the circuit, like this:

[image]

thus now I am sensing the voltage across same 47 Ohm resistor in series with V_GS. This is OK, since I only need signal's timing and I am not interested in amplitude's absolute value of the signal. The measurements I take now make more sense (I added second probe to plot the input signal):

[image]
[image]

I get a measurement of t_ON time (voltage drop on resistor + V_GS) around 60 ns, as expected:

[image]
[image]

I get a measurement of t_OFF time (voltage rise on resistor + V_GS) around 295ns, as expected:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The only question is... why it doesn't work when I perform floating measurement across resistor only, and it's fine if gnd tip of the probe connects to circuit's GND?

Comment: You need 10:1 probe with both tip and gnd clip removed to 2 short pins to measure fastest risetime

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Many thanks. Now I can see clearly it's the heavy capacitive loading of the probe+scope that's the root of the problem. I did this test on X1, my bad, however x10 gives same time measurements, probably presenting same capacitance to the circuit? Should I have more luck with x100 or maybe go for active amplifier probe? I will yet try shorten the tip and gnd of the passive probe.

Comment: Use the short pin and coax barrel of probe

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I shortened gnd and tip connections of probe but inductance/capacitance loaded by scope did not change, please see [EDIT 1]. Could this be that it's introduced by cheap signal generator I use (JDS 6600) and not scope?

Comment: yes.normally one compares input to output, but also uses the same technique on the probe for the sig.gen. Not long alligator clip jumpers which adds 10nH per cm approx. in a loop. That means 500 ns rise time with a 1cm loop into 50 ohms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rise times typically < 50 ns must be done on 50 Ohm controlled impedance PCB’s with coaxial connectors to/from the DUT.    Wire leads add 500 ns per cm pigtail wire loop into a 50 Ohm load. Then add gate resistance and gate capacitance to the load.

Following the component test schematic is logical and assumes you understand the physical implications and have the necessary test equipment.   In this ultra fast FET case, you would need an Active FET probe with a faster risetime and load <<1pF with a resistive divider from 450 to 50 Ohms.  With AC coupling from Gnd test lead to V+ using < =100pF NPO ceramic.

The sig gen could be 50 ohm coax with a short pigtail soldered to the resistor, if you wanted a make-shift test. Then Gnd’s must be single point short as possible with good RF ceramic cap across the DUT.  ~ 100pF//1nF V+/0V

Comment: Many thanks Tony. I really appreciate your hints, thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. However, I got good readings when I connected gnd tip of the probe to GND of the circuit (please see [EDIT 2]). Would you have any idea why this did the thing?

Comment: yes it’s in my answer, inductance is a loop characteristic including Gnd

Comment: That’s what they paid the big bucks for!